# List in another list, but the elements of the first list don‘t need to occure one after another in the second list

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I have 2 different lists that i want to compare.
I want to know if all elements of the first list occure in the second list regarding the ordering of the elements of the first list, but elements do not need to occure directly one after another in the second list.
For example:
`list1 = [3, 11, 17]`
`list2= [54, 3, 23, 17, 11, 50, 17]`
For this two lists the function should return `True` because every element of `list1` occures in

```
list2 = [54, 3, 23, 17, 11, 50, 17]
```

in the order of `list1`.
The order of the elements of each list should not be changed and the lists can have elements of the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this by using error handling and `index` method from lists. Let's define the following function:

```
def compare_lists(list1, list2):
    start = 0
    for y in list1:
        try:
            start = list2.index(y, start) + 1
        except ValueError:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

For each element of `list1`, we look into `list2` for its first occurrence after the last element found. If it is found, we save its index in a variable `start` and keep looking for the next element in `list2` starting from the `start + 1` index.

If the element is not found, the `index` method throws a `ValueError`, which we catch and use to return `False`. If no error is thrown, then the lists passed the test and we return `True`.

Tell us if you have any further issues.

Comment: For these two instances `[3, 3, 17, 17, 17]` and `[54, 3, 3, 23, 17, 11, 50, 11, 17]` , the function returns `True`. But obviously should return `False`.

Comment: This is almost looking as a Kata from CodeWars hahah. My mistake, now it should run correctly